# ERROR when mounting RHEL samba share on another RHEL server

Tags: linux, samba, mount, cifs, share

I have a server (let's call it ServerA) where I have configured two Samba shares, that are currently accessed from a few Windows computers with no issues.

I've also been able to mount these two shares in ServerB, but when doing the same thing in ServerC (a server with very similar configurations as ServerB: RHEL 5) using this command:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<username>,password=<password> //ServerA/logs /mnt/logs
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //ServerA/logs,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

The destination /mnt/logs exists and has the correct permissions.

What could be the reason for this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That could be caused by not having the cifs-utils package installed.

```
yum list cifs*
```

If you don't see cifs-utils then;

```
yum install -y cifs-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Install cifs-utils on serverC. Seems it doesn't know what cifs is.